# update list code doesn't seem to working

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom

I am trying to update to update list when user clicks on "Edit" button but below code doesn't seem to be working..

```
<h1 align="center">DemoList</h1>
<table id="maintable">
<tr>
<td>Title</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="TitleId"/>
</td>
<td>Manager</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="ManagerId"/>
</td>
<td>Department</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="DepartmentId"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="editList()">Edit</button>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dept-dev.int.ally.com/sites/EA/Style%20Library/Scripts/Jquery/jquery.min.js" >
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">  
var collListItem;  
$(document).ready(function () {
try
{
    getSetListItem();
}
catch(e)
{
    alert("error occured at ready method" + e.message);
}
}); 


function getSetListItem() {  

   var  qString = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
   var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DemoList');  
   var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Numeric\'>'+ qString +'</Value></Eq></Where> </Query></View>');  
   collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);  
   clientContext.load(collListItem);  
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, OnLoadSuccess),  
   Function.createDelegate(this, OnLoadFailed));  
}  

function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {  
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();  
   while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {  
      var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();  
      $("#DepartmentId").val(oListItem.get_item("Department"))+$("#TitleId").val(oListItem.get_item("Title"));

document.getElementById('ManagerId').value = oListItem.get_item("Manager").get_lookupValue();

}
} 
function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {  
   alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
   }  

   function editList()
   {
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DemoList');
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
   camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Numeric\'>'+ qString +'</Value></Eq></Where> </Query></View>');  
   collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);  
     oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



</script>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what error you are getting ?

Comment: function editList() not giving desired o/p....and caml query in editlist not returning any value

Answer (score 0):

Please Update "**editList**" function as follows and let me know if it is working  -

```
function editList()
{   
    var qString = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DemoList');
    var oListItem =  oList.getItemById(ItemId); //ItemId will be ID of an item you are updating.
    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');
    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

Comment: nope..its not working

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code. Below are the issue and updated code

1. You are querying the same list item on load as well as on edit button click. You can improve this by storing the list item and use it on edit
2. On `EditList` function you are trying to use undefined object `oListItem`

I have updated your code as below

```
<h1 align="center">DemoList</h1>
<table id="maintable">
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="TitleId"/></td>
        <td>Manager</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ManagerId"/></td>
        <td>Department</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="DepartmentId"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="editList()">Edit</button>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dept-dev.int.ally.com/sites/EA/Style%20Library/Scripts/Jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">  
    var collListItem;  
    var oListItem;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            getSetListItem();
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert("error occured at ready method" + e.message);
        }
    }); 

    function getSetListItem() {  
       var  qString = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
       var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
       var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DemoList');  
       var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();  
       camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Value Type=\'Numeric\'>'+ qString +'</Value></Eq></Where> </Query></View>');  
       collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);  
       clientContext.load(collListItem);  
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, OnLoadSuccess),  
       Function.createDelegate(this, OnLoadFailed));  
    }  

    function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {  
        var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();  
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {  
          oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();  
          $("#TitleId").val(oListItem.get_item("Title"));
          $("#DepartmentId").val(oListItem.get_item("Department"));
          $("#ManagerId").val(oListItem.get_item("Manager").get_lookupValue());
          break;
        }
    } 

    function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {  
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
    }  

    function editList() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DemoList');
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title');
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert('Item updated!');
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: no o/p coming..in debugger...control doesnt reach olistitem.update();

Comment: You mean the editList function is not getting executed?

Comment: no it didnt got executed

Comment: Replace <button onclick="editList()">Edit</button> with <input type='button' onclick='editList();' value='Edit'/>

Comment: now its showing : oListItem is undefined